# nonlinear matrix equation solving in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation-solving

is it possible to solve below equation in matlab?

```
A*X+B*exp(X)=C
```

A, B are square and constant matrices. C is a constant and column matrix.
X is a column matrix which should be found.( exp() acts element by element on X).

Comment: Symbolic toolbox available? Then try http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html. You need to initialize the sym X with correct size, otherwise it will fail: `X=sym('X',size(C))`

Comment: yes. it is available. i solved it by fsolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a numeric method, you might want to try [`fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html)

```
X = fsolve( @(x) A*x + B*exp(x) - C, x0 );
```

Due to the non-linear nature of the problem you need to provide an initial guess `x0` - the quality of which can affect the performance of the solver.

Comment: @iliailiaey Then please mark the answer as accepted (green checkmark at the top of the answer). Thanks!